# Почему "потому что" пишется раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Почему "потому что" пишется раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это сложный (составной) подчинительный союз. Иногда простые союзы  в нём даже разделяются запятой. Можно написать Она ему нравилась, потому что была очень красива (акцент на результат) или Она ему нравилась потому, что была очень красива (акцент на причину).

Answer (score 1):

Вторую часть этого союза ЧТО очень часто путают с частицей (или суффиксом) -ТО, которая пишется через дефис с местоимениями, наречиями (ср.: потому-то). У многих  возникает желание и слово ПОТОМУ ЧТО писать через дефис, хотя союз образовался из двух вполне самостоятельных слов ПОТОМУ и ЧТО и никакой дефис для их написания не требуется.